# How many cpus needed to check a 100 million digit prime number efficiently?

Tags: prime-numbers, computability-theory, computational-number-theory, computer-science

If I had access to potentially unlimited CPUs and wanted to quickly check 100 million digit numbers for primality using a map-reduce architecture, how many CPUs would be necessary? Each of the mapped compute instances would perform efficient checks against the number in question with an assigned range of divisors (e.g. Instance 1: checks divisors 1-1000, Instance 2: checks divisors 1001-2000, ... etc.).

Definitions:

> **quickly** means checking a 100 million digit number within 30-60 minutes.
>
> **efficient division** means checking odd numbers up to the square root.
>
> **1 CPU** is the equivalent CPU capacity of a 1.0-1.2 GHz 2007 Opteron or 2007 Xeon processor.

The better question to ask would probably be: what is the mathematical relationship between the number of CPUs and the amount of time it takes to verify a number of a given magnitude of digits?

Comment: OK, but what's 'primeality'?

Comment: Well, one to hold the light bulb,

Comment: Anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test and then try 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest  



Comment: The question implicitly assumes that the primality testing is by trial division, which is actually a bad primality test, even with massive parallelization. Nevertheless, if the question is roughly how many trial divisions are needed, it's about the square root of the number. Ok, so a $10^8$ decimal digit number needs about $10^{\frac{1}{2}10^8}$ trial divisions. No, no typo. With, let's say, $10^{10}$ CPUs (is this how many substantial computers exist in the world?), each one would need to do about $10^{\frac{1}{2}10^8−10}$ trial divisions. That −10 in the exponent is not helping much... 

Comment: I realize there are more efficient ways but how would you go about dividing the problem for map-reduce? Say I used AKS Primality testing or one of the other more efficient algorithms?

Comment: I think the final form of the question is pretty clear and research level. My interpretation of the question is: "is it possible given an unlimited amount of cpus to check the primality of a 100 million digits number in under an hour". Looking up the specs and time it took for verifying the primality of the 46th Mersenne prime, the answer is surely no, but not too far from a yes (5 days on 4 quadcores). To be able to do a 100 million digits number, a huge amount of work and money must go into developing extremely faster memory, as it is the primary bottleneck of a parallel implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a bit unclear, still I will try to give some sort of answer.

Some intial remarks:

First, at the moment noone suceed in proving primality for a 100 million (decimal) digit number. The current record is (I believe) close to 13 million digits (in binary this would still not be 100 million).

Second, one does not do these test by trial division as your description seems to suggest.

Having said this, as a thought experiment a very rough and overly optimistic calculation:

Suppose you have a 100 million digit number. Then you will have to test whether it is divisibile by numbers of size up to its square root, that is 50 million digit numbers. 
So, you test $10^{50 000 000}$ numbers.

Suppose you do your divison with only one processor instruction. I am not overly knowledgeable on processor speeds but according to [the list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions%252Dper%252Dsecond) let's assume you do 50 GIPS so $5*10^9$ instruction per second.

Now, in an hour you will do, let's be generous, $2*10^{12}$ instructions, by our assumption divisoions.

So you need $10^{50 000 000}/(2*10^{12}) = 5 * 10^{49 999 987}$ processors.

As said, you cannot do this like this. Also note that using the approach you sketch you would effectively find a factor and thus a factorization. For factoring the current records are way smaller then the ones for primes I mentioned above. It is a major challenge to factor numbers with (low) hundreds of digits. Note that that current RSA-keys are of size a a thousand or two (maybe four) thousand bits. So (higher) hundreds to a thousand decimal digits only.

P.S. Towards the end of my writing, I saw paul garrett's comment which is similar. Perhaps the details are useful. And, sorry to those who mind, for answering the off-topic question.

Comment: See Mariano's post, it refers to Joel David Hamkins:

http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/482/what-about-questions-on-the-history-of-mathematics/#Item_9

Comment: I could store all of the known contiguous prime numbers and check against those and then perform trial division of odd numbers up to the square root. If I don't do trial division, how else will I divide and conquer in map-reduce?

Comment: As a first step, you could do Euclid's gcd algorithm with products of some of the primes.  Even if you could do this quickly with, say, products of a million primes each time, that only reduces the exponent above by one or two orders of magnitude.  There is still the problem of generating the products for use in such an endeavour.
  Better to read up on AKS.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.22

Comment: Adam F, regarding 'storing primes' to do something for 100 million digit numbers. Note that up to size x there are about x/log x primes. Thus up to 10^50000000 there are something like (taking 4 as approx for nat log of 10) 10^50000000/ (2 *10^8) = 5 * 10^4999991 primes. This is an insanely large number relative to say a Terabyte (10^12). I do not know about the specifics of Map Reduce, but a couple more general remarks/questions:



Comment: a. Do you want to find a prime of this size or test one specific number (if the latter I would be curious why)?
For the former: there is a monetary award of the EFF of 150.000$ for the first 100 million digit prime. So, besides scientific interest, there would be a simple economic interest in finding such a prime, if it were feasible (with a cost of less than that amount).

b. The largest known primes are all Mersenne primes and as such of a particular form. It also makes a difference if you want to test a generic number or one of a particular form.



Comment: c. Prime testing is a complicated. There are many test and good progs combine various test. This can include trial divison up to some threshold.
See for example for an overview of methods  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test and
http://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~belabas/pari/doc/faq.html#primetest for some words what is done in an actual program.
As AKS got mentioned, it is my understanding, from e.g. the PARI link above, despite its great theoretical importance, it is not actually used much (this info is a bit dated 2006, but also in 06 the algo was around since a while).  



Comment: d. One more data point. Acording to Ribenboim, The little book of bigger primes (2004) the (then) largest number proved prime (in 03) with a general purpose algorithm  was (only) 5878 digits, using about 3500 hours on a then good processor. The method used was ECPP (eliptic curve primality proving) by Atkin--Morain; this is parallizable, search for papers of Morain. END

Comment: Incidentally, the natural log of 10 is closer to 2 than it is to 3.

Comment: S. Carnaham, thanks, so I definitely should not have taken 4 as approximation...I believe I wanted to use the ceiling to rather give a too low estimate for the primes, and somehow confused base 2 and natural.